# How to make line break in ul horizontal list for every x list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have horizontal dynamic `ul` list build by PHP like this:

```
List1 List2 List3 List4 List5 List6 List7 List8 List9 List10
```

Is there a way to make new line every 3 lists? So, the result will look like this:

```
List1 List2 List3

List4 List5 List6

List7 List8 List9

List10
```

I know I can adjust the `ul` width to make my lists look like above.

But what I want is to make new line for every 3 lists. Is PHP, CSS, or JavaScript can do this? Anyone can help?

Comment: if you post your PHP code, I can help you also... with php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have fixed sizes of you list items you can do it simple with jQuery:

```
$('li:nth-child(3n)').next().css({'clear': 'both'});
```

This takes every third element, and add clear to the next one. That's way .. no matter what size is your list item it will take the next after every 3th element to new line.

Comment: When I use your method in my code, it failed. So I try it in CSS, and it works great, thanks... :)

Answer (score 10):

How about just -

```
li {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Setting the width of each `li` element to one third of the available space means we can fit three floated `li`'s on every line, before the browser pushes the next one onto a new line.

I guess you could probably swap the `float: left` statement for `display: inline` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

As Панайот Толев mentioned in his post but only with CSS3:

```
li:nth-child(3n) + li
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Select every 3rd element and add a clear:both to the next following list element

Answer (score 1):

You have to set every `<li>` width - for example `width: 100px;` and for `<ul>` set `width: 300px`.

```
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 300px;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: seems best to do this with css, but OP specified that the list was horizontally dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with PHP and not css (as @hsz suggested), you can split it in `ul`'s that have a maximum of 3 `li`'s in them

```
<ul class="...">
<?php
$i = 1;
$array = (/* 10 items */);
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($i % 3 == 0) { echo '</ul><ul>'; }
    echo "<li>{$item}</li>";
    $i ++;
}
?></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the following will fill the space and break when no space. This for use with for loop when u have unknown number of item.

When using fixed number of items u can add a line break 
second example below.

```
    .pagination {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

then

```
  <div class="pagination" >
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
</div>
```

this is for fixed line break

```
    <div class="pagination" >
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <br>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
    <a>text</a>
</div>
```